# How to add a custom plugin to ckeditor in Angular that adds a custom table, any exemple?

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor4.x

I have tried to add the following code to index.html like that

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>AngularCkeditor</title>
      <base href="/">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body>
      <app-root></app-root>
      <script src="assets/ckeditor/dist/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But it does not work. I also tried to import it in the component like that

```
`import CKEDITOR from '../assets/ckeditor/dist/bundle.js';
```

` but it did not work because Angular uses virtual DOM using the classic way ( install ckeditor component for angular ). There appears to be no documentation or tutorials on this matter for custom table plugin -
help please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i add the following code in my angular component

```
 <h1>an angular component to test  Ckeditor</h1>
    <ckeditor [editor]="editor" data="<p>Bonjour Ckeditor</p>"></ckeditor>
```

and i add my custom build to assets
[project architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx7qL.png)

i compiled my ckeditor using webpack with this command :

```
webpack --mode production
```

and finally

i imported my compiled ckeditor to my angular component using

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '../assets/ckeditor5-build-classic/';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use NPM package available for CKeditor.

NPM package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular

Documentation:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/angular.html

This will be the better approach to use CKeditor.

Comment: i know that and i tried but  there is no  documentation how to add custom plugin ( custom table ) by using angular component

Comment: Have you tried this https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/table.html and https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/table.html ?